# Matlab error Unsupported image datatype 'struct'

Tags: matlab

Currently I am working on matlab for an image processing project and I am simpley capturing an image with my webcam, saving it, processing the image using the hough transform and then trying to save it. When I use the imwrite function on the transformed image I get this error:

```
??? Error using ==> imwrite>validateSizes at 596
Unsupported image datatype 'struct'.

Error in ==> imwrite at 422
validateSizes(data);

Error in ==> findLine at 48
imwrite(tapes,fullImageFileName2);
```

I dont really know whats going on here but I use the imwrite function when the image is first taken by the webcam and That saves with no errors. Its the second time I try to save an image, which is the transformed image I get this error. Anyone any ideas?

This is my code so far:

```
vidobj = videoinput('winvideo');
preview(vidobj);
pause(10);
snapshot = getsnapshot(vidobj);
fullImageFileName = fullfile(pwd, 'line.jpg');
imwrite(snapshot,fullImageFileName);
imagesc(snapshot);
imshow(snapshot);

%Load image
tape = imread('C:\Users\Mustafa\Documents\MATLAB\line.jpg');
%Displays the valid values for the Image Processing
iptsetpref ImshowBorder tight
imshow(tape)

%Segment by thresh holding
thresh1 = 100;
tapes = im2bw(tape, thresh1/255);
imshow(tapes)

%Clean up image
%Morphology to assist segmentation
tapes = bwareaopen(tapes,100);%area under 100 pixels
imshow(tapes)

%Clear objects touching the line
%suppresses structures that are lighter than their surroundings and that are connected        to the image border. 
%(In other words, use this function to clear the image border.)
%tapes = imclearborder(tapes, 26);
%imshow(tapes)

%Find tape
%Find all connected regions
[B,L] = bwboundaries(tapes, 'noholes');
numRegions = max(L(:));
imshow(label2rgb(L))


%Hough transform
[H, theta, rho] = hough(tapes);
peaks = houghpeaks(H, 2);
tapes = houghlines(tapes, theta, rho, peaks, 'FillGap', 50, 'MinLength', 30);



fullImageFileName2 = fullfile(pwd, 'linedetect.png');
imwrite(tapes,fullImageFileName2,'BitDepth',16);
```

Comment: We need more information, can you type `whos tapes` and report what it says. (It looks like `tapes` is a struct, so would also be good to show how you creates `tapes`.)

Comment: I have updated my code above,

Comment: tapes = houghlines(tapes, theta, rho, peaks, 'FillGap', 50, 'MinLength', 30);

Comment: after typing 'whos tapes', this is what I get: >> whos tapes
  Name       Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  tapes      1x3              1120  struct

Answer (score 1):

`houghlines` returns a `struct`.   Type `help houghlines` to understand what the output is more thoroughly.

(Hint, it's not an image.)

At the bottom of the help page for `houghlines` it gives an example of what do do with the output.